# Jquery effects .queue()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation, effect

This is the site i'm working on: http://www.sircat.net/joomla/sircat/mies/calendari.html

When I click on any year column (2012, 2011, 2010, etc) it shows the content of each year and hide the other ones.

The problem it's that when I click (2011 column for example), the animation does all the effects at the same time confusing the user, I think I have to do it with animation steps, but I haven't been able to come to a jquery solution.

This is my code:

```
/* Scroll Function */
function scrollto(position){
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollLeft: position
    }, 1000);
}

/* Calendar Scroll */
$(".sub_section_title").click( function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".contenido_calendario").hide();
    $(this).next(".contenido_calendario").toggle('slow');
    scrollto($(this).offset().left - 352)
});
```

I have tried fixing the effect by using .queue() but it doesn't work, I don't know if the code it's well written also:

```
$(".sub_section_title").click( function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".contenido_calendario").hide();
    $(".contenido_calendario").queue(function() {
        scrollto($(this).offset().left - 352);
        $(this).dequeue();
    });
    $(".contenido_calendario").queue(function() {
        $(this).next(".contenido_calendario").toggle('slow')
    $(this).dequeue();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use callback functions:

```
/* Scroll Function */
function scrollto(position){
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollLeft: position
    }, 1000);
}

/* Calendar Scroll */
$(".sub_section_title").click( function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this)
    $(".contenido_calendario").hide(function(){
      $this.next(".contenido_calendario").toggle('slow',function(){
        scrollto($(this).offset().left - 352)
      });
    }); 
});
```

Comment: I have changed it to that, but now it makes a double toggle (click on 2011 and see), this is so hard, oh god... ty anyway Abraham!